# ShapeRange Objects are acting weirdly

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

**Sorry if this is long. I had to explain everything.**

I have the following three moduels:
1. CreateDemoMap
2. CreateDemoTable
3. Update

The CreateDemoMap will go through a table and get the location (Top and Left), size (Width and Length), Name, Rotation and title of shapes and place them on the screen. Basically, it will build a map. This is the main part of my code:

```
For i = 2 To endNum 'input the number manual for now

Top = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(i, 2)
Left = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(i, 3)
Width = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(i, 4)
Height = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(i, 5)
Name = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(i, 6)
Rotation = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(i, 7)
Title = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(i, 8)

Set sh = w.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Left, Top, Width, Height)
    sh.Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = Rotation
    Selection.ShapeRange.Title = Title
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = Name

Next i
```

Here is a screenshot of my table and the map:

#### Map & Table

[image: Map & Table]

Next, I thought it would be cool to go through the shape range array and get the properties of each objects. Also, it enabled me get the shape ID.

```
Sub Test1()

Dim Top As Long
Dim Left As Long
Dim Width As Long
Dim Height As Long
Dim ID As String
Dim Name As String
Dim Rotation As String
Dim Title As String

Dim sh As Object
Dim endNum As Integer

CreateSheet ("DemoTable")

totalShape = 90
rnr = 2
IndexNum = 0

Worksheets("DemoMap").Activate

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    IndexNum = IndexNum + 1
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 1) = IndexNum
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 2) = shp.Top
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 3) = shp.Left
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 4) = shp.Width
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 5) = shp.Height
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 6) = shp.ID
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 7) = shp.Name
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 9) = shp.Rotation
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 10) = shp.Title
    Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(rnr, 11) = shp.Type

rnr = rnr + 1
Next shp

End Sub
```

This is how it looks like:

#### Shape Table

[image: ShapeTable]

---

Objectives:
A. update the Top, Left, and rotation of the shapes if the objects were moved or rotated.
B. Be able to account for deleted and added shapes

Solutions:
A. Since there wasn't an event listener in VBA, I decided to let the user move the objects however she want and then click a button that would update the table you saw earlier. Here is my code for this sub:

```
Sub UpdateShapes()

Dim Top As Long
Dim Left As Long
Dim Width As Long
Dim Height As Long
Dim ID As String
Dim Name As String
Dim Rotation As String
Dim Title As String
Dim sh As Object
Dim endNum As Integer
Dim Changes As Integer

Dim JSBChanges As Integer
Dim OneChanges As Integer
Dim TwoChanges As Integer
Dim ThreeChanges As Integer
Dim M1Changes As Integer
Dim M2Changes As Integer
Dim Deleted As Integer
Dim myDoc As Worksheet
Dim ShapeNum As Integer
Dim ShapeIndex As Integer

JSBChanges = 0
OneChanges = 0
TwoChanges = 0
ThreeChanges = 0
M1Changes = 0
M2Changes = 0
Deleted = 0



Set myDoc = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoMap")
ShapeNum = myDoc.Shapes.Count
Debug.Print ("ShapeNum is: " & ShapeNum)

Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoMap").Activate

TableIndex = 2
ShapeIndex = 1

While (TableIndex <= (ShapeNum + 1))
    Changes = 0
If(Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(TableIndex, 6) = myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).ID) Then
    If (Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(TableIndex, 2) <> myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).Top) Then
        Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(TableIndex, 2) = myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).Top
        Changes = Changes + 1
    End If
    If (Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(TableIndex, 3) <> myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).Left) Then
        Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(TableIndex, 3) = myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).Left
        Changes = Changes + 1
    End If
    If (Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(TableIndex, 9) <> myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).Rotation) Then
        Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Cells(TableIndex, 9) = myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).Rotation
        Changes = Changes + 1
    End If

    If (Changes >= 1) Then

    With myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With


    Select Case (myDoc.Shapes.Range(ShapeIndex).Title)
        Case "JSB"
            JSBChanges = JSBChanges + 1
        Case "1"
            OneChanges = OneChanges + 1
        Case "2"
            TwoChanges = TwoChanges + 1
        Case "3"
            ThreeChanges = ThreeChanges + 1
        Case "M1"
            M1Changes = M1Changes + 1
        Case "M2"
            M2Changes = M2Changes + 1
    End Select

    End If
Else
    Deleted = Deleted + 1
    Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Rows(TableIndex).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("DemoTable").Rows(TableIndex).Font.ColorIndex = 2
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ShapeIndex = ShapeIndex - 1

End If

    TableIndex = TableIndex + 1
    ShapeIndex = ShapeIndex + 1
    ShapeNum = myDoc.Shapes.Count
Wend

MsgBox ("JSBChanges: " & JSBChanges)
MsgBox ("OneChanges: " & OneChanges)
MsgBox ("TwoChanges: " & TwoChanges)
MsgBox ("ThreeChanges: " & ThreeChanges)
MsgBox ("M1Changes: " & M1Changes)
MsgBox ("M2Changes: " & M2Changes)
MsgBox ("Deleted: " & Deleted)

End Sub
```

Let's assume no shape has been added or deleted, which means the shaperange array should have the same number of objects. Thru. trail and error, I also discovered that the array elements won't move around and will stay still if you move your objects around. So, as you see, the code will compare the elements inside the DemoTable I just created with the elements inside the shaperange array. I can verify that this works if I start move things around. It will successfully update the Top and Left properties of the shapes that have been displaced.

Problem/Challenge/Issue:
Then I expanded the code, so it would identify if a shape has been deleted. As you see in my code, the fourth row in my table (Table Index = 4) should be the same (thus have the same shape ID) as the third element in the ShapeRange array. However if the third shape is deleted, the array get shrunk, which means the third element in the new (updated automaically) shapeRange array is the fourth element in the old array. This is useful, because then you can use this to figure out if a shape has been deleted or not. If the ID associated with TabeIndex = 4 is the same as Shape Index = 3, then that means that the object described by TableIndex = 4 has been deleted and the Shape associate with Shape Index = 3 should be the same as the one referenced by Table Index = 5 (the next shape). That's why, I added ShapeIndex = ShapeIndex - 1.

Make the story short, this works sometimes, but the other times it's not accurate. Last night I deleted 20 shapes and ran the sub. It told me that 17 objects were deleted. I spend hours looking the results and debugging the code, but found nothing. This evening, I ran the code again after deleting 15 objects. Here is my updated table:

#### Updated Demo Table

[image: UpdatedDemoTable]

Those red lines mean that that row (particular shape) has been deleted. In this case, I deleted 15 shapes, but it only shows that only 12 shapes have been deleted. Obviously this not right. As I said earlier, it happened last night too. It's not consistent at all. To prove this, I used a similar code as my CreateDemMap sub. Basically, it goes through each objects in the worksheet and make a table just like before. If everything would've gone right, this table should be exactly the same as my Demo Table (assuming if I delete those red rows). It's NOT!

#### New Table For Checking

[image: NewTableForChecking]

The new table I extracted from the ShapeRange array tells me that there are 70 shapes in the array (15 were deleted which is the correct number), but in my DemoTable, only 12 rows were highlighted as red. Why is this happening? Last night, I deleted a particular shape with a specific shape ID. By doing this, I was sure that that shape object would not be in the ShapeRange Array. However, when I was debugging, I realized that wasn't the case. The object was gone from my screen, but its shape ID (and consequently the shape itself) was still in the ShapeRange Array. Why is VBA Excel acting like this? Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to understand all your code - but I think your problem is because you're ending your loop too early. It runs until `ShapeNum` which is the number of shapes you have in your sheet. When you delete some shapes, this number is lower than the number of entries in your table and the last entries in the table are not checked.